# Is the boundary of the convex hull of a closed, smooth surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ also a closed, smooth surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology, surfaces, convex-hulls

I have recently been looking for results giving insight into whether the statement in the title is true or only sometimes true.  Does anyone know of any results and/or papers or books related to this claim?

Comment: the convex hull of the sphere is the closed ball which surely isn't a surface

Comment: What about the boundary of the convex hull?

Comment: The question refers to the boundary of the hull, not the hull itself.

Comment: If you embed the sphere in a funny way—embedded like how we think of a direct sum of two spheres, but say of two different radii—it seems like the boundary of its convex hull should be a cone-like object at the smaller end, and that would not be a smoothly embedded manifold. If that's so, making it precise sounds annoying, but it should be doable.

Comment: What is the direct sum in this context?  Is it the union of two disjoint spheres?

Comment: Would making the initial closed, smooth connected make the claim true?

Comment: @FabrizzioMuzz you're right, I have misread your question. Apologize

Comment: @FabrizzioMuzz Oh gosh, I'm sorry. I meant "connect sum," not direct sum! Not sure why I said that. I think the disjoint union of two spheres would work too.

Comment: Shouldn't the convex hull of the connected sum of two spheres be convex (Google "minimal surface convex hulls of spheres")?

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth"? There is no canonical definition here, as some people require $C^\infty$, some merely $C^1$, etc.

Comment: By smooth, I mean $C^1$.